# Are there any "natural problems" which are known to be NPI under weak assumptions

Tags: complexity-theory, complexity-classes, np-intermediate

Are there any "natural problems" which are known to be NPI under weak assumptions.
By weak assumptions I mean something like $P \neq NP$ or $NP \neq Co-NP$

Comment: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/7854/32254 mentions an example under the assumption that P != NP, but I suppose it's not considered "natural".

Comment: The same question was asked here: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/79/problems-between-p-and-npc?noredirect=1&lq=1